# passing one list of values instead of mutiple arguments to a function?

Tags: python, list, function, arguments

Lets say there's a function `func()` which takes two arguments, `a` and `b`. Is there some kind of technique in Python to pass a single list `mylist` which has both values to the function instead?

```
def myfunc(a, b):
    return a+b

myfunc([1, 2])
```

If one was completely sure that he was always calling the same function and knew how many arguments it takes, one could do something like this:

```
mylist = [1, 2]
a, b = mylist

myfunc(a, b)
```

But what if you have lists you need to feed to certain functions, and each has different amount of arguments?
One could write separate lines of code for each of his functions to unpack the lists into variables and pass them to the corresponding functions, but if Python has something built-in to pass a single list instead of individual argument values (when being sure beforehand that list has the corresponding amount of values), then that would look a lot better and most importantly would require far less lines of code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `*` to [unpack the list into arguments](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
myfunc(*mylist)
```

Comment: I knew Python would have something like this!

Comment: @user975135 This can also be done with dicts, which is useful for keyword arguments or calling functions with many arguments: `mydict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}` `myfunc(**mydict)`

Answer (score 4):

```
def myfunc(a, b):
    return a+b

mylist = [1, 2]
myfunc(*mylist)
```

Here `mylist` can be `list`, `tuple`, `string` etc of length 2.