# Passing List to Function in place of Many Arguments

Tags: python, list

First, I apologize if a similar question has been addressed. I looked but had no luck (which could be from me not knowing how to properly search for this question.) In it's simplest form, suppose we have the following:

```
def func(x, a, b):
    return a*x + b*b

c = [2, 3]
```

How would you use the function like, `func(x, c)`? Specifically, rather than writing out an entire array's elements as arguments to a function, how do you cleanly in place of the arguments reference an array?

Comment: Use unpacking: `func(x, *c)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [passing one list of values instead of mutiple arguments to a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064406/passing-one-list-of-values-instead-of-mutiple-arguments-to-a-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *extended iterable unpacking operator*.

```
def func(x, a, b):
    return a*x + b*b

c = [2, 3]
func(x,*c)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much. Unpacking,  I'll try to remember this.

Comment: @CaptainMorgan, you're welcome! Don't forget to accept answer in order to help other people.

Comment: I haven't forgotten. I tried to accept it but had to wait 15nin. I just accepted it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer might be: Packing

When we don’t know how many arguments need to be passed to a python function, we can use Packing to pack all arguments in a tuple.

```
# A Python program to demonstrate use
# of packing

# This function uses packing to sum
# unknown number of arguments
def mySum(*args):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(0, len(args)):
        sum = sum + args[i]
    return sum

# Driver code
print(mySum(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
print(mySum(10, 20))
```